# Remove "CHECKOUT METHOD" from onepage

Tags: onepage-checkout

By default, the words "CHECKOUT METHOD" are displayed over the first step on Magento 1.9.2.   I need to remove those words.   I can not find where to edit this line.  Does anyone know?

Thank you,

Please see image below.
[image]